# How to select data from a table which has inter-related data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table `OBJECTS` with `columns Id, parent id, object_type and name`.

I have real time object types as `Groups, Accounts and Services`. They are hierarchical in the same order. That means, Groups contains Accounts and Accounts contains Services. So, `service.parent_id` will refer to `account.object_id` and `account.parent_id` will refer to `group.object_id` within the same table.

Criteria fields for selecting data must be passed as parameters to the query. Now, if the User provides a Group ID, then the query must fetch all Services that are belonged to all the Accounts within that group.
Similarly, if the user provides ID for Account, the query must return all the Services under the Account.

I have written the following query, but it doesn't work exactly I need. Can someone help me fix it?

```
WITH services AS
  (SELECT nco.object_id,
          nco.parent_id,
          nco.object_type_id,
          nco.name
   FROM objects nco
   WHERE nco.object_type_id = 9146522450013755288 ),
     accounts AS
  (SELECT nco.object_id,
          nco.parent_id,
          nco.name
   FROM objects nco,
        services ss
   WHERE nco.object_type_id=9145485031713653586
     AND nco.object_id = ss.parent_id ),
     groups AS
  (SELECT nco.object_id,
          nco.parent_id,
          nco.name
   FROM objects nco,
        accounts sa
   WHERE nco.object_id = sa.parent_id
     AND nco.object_type_id = 9146513648413722258 )
SELECT *
FROM services ss,
     accounts sa,
     groups sg
WHERE ss.object_id IN (#Services#)
  OR sa.object_id IN (#Accounts#)
  OR sg.object_id IN (#Groups#)
```

Input is passed as Macros using `(##)` and there can be multiple Group ID's, Account ID's and Service ID's passed. `object_type_id` is a column which will identify what type of object it is. For example, 9146513648413722258 refers to Services, 9145485031713653586 refers to Accounts etc.

Comment: "it doesn't work exactly I need" isn't a useful description of your problem. What goes wrong?

Comment: It is fetching wrong data. There is some problem with my conditions, the way I'm joining the tables

Comment: "fetching wrong data" is once again not very helpful. What results did you expect, and what did you get? Give examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, an `inner join` makes more sense that a full join `,`, therefore

```
SELECT services.*
FROM objects groups 
INNER JOIN objects accounts 
    ON groups.object_type_id=9146522450013755288
    AND accounts.object_type_id=9146513648413722258
    AND accounts.parent_id=groups.object_id
INNER JOIN objects services 
    ON services.object_type_id=9145485031713653586
    AND services.parent_id=accounts.object_id
WHERE services.object_id IN (#Services#)
  OR accounts.object_id IN (#Accounts#)
  OR groups.object_id IN (#Groups#)
```

The query joins the `services`, `accounts` and `groups` table (implicitly from the `objects` table) using the `parent_id` and then filter out the result.

Comment: There's no full join in OP's original query. There are, however, two cross joins. The advice to use inner joins and (implicitly) to rewrite using ANSI syntax is correct.